# suspicious/unfamiliar packages with anaconda and pip?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I only just downloaded anaconda and the package list looks really long. Does this look normal? When i type `conda list` in the terminal I get the following (this is just a small subset, the list is really long):

alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anaconda-client           1.11.2          py310hca03da5_0
anaconda-navigator        2.4.0           py310hca03da5_0
anaconda-project          0.11.1          py310hca03da5_0
anyio                     3.5.0           py310hca03da5_0
appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
applaunchservices         0.3.0           py310hca03da5_0
appnope                   0.1.2           py310hca03da5_1001
appscript                 1.1.2           py310h1a28f6b_0
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py310h1a28f6b_0
arrow                     1.2.3           py310hca03da5_1
astroid                   2.14.2          py310hca03da5_0
astropy                   5.1             py310h96f19d2_0
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     22.1.0          py310hca03da5_0
automat                   20.2.0                     py_0
autopep8                  1.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
babel                     2.11.0          py310hca03da5_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports                 1.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0

Similar happens when I type `pip list` - there is also a long list of packages I am not familiar with.

Completely reinstalled anaconda and python but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks reasonable. Anaconda comes with a ton of preinstalled stuff - check the [docs](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/reference/packages/pkg-docs/) for a list of expected packages.

If you have the official distribution installed from anaconda.com (you can also check the [file hash](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/reference/hashes/index.html) to make sure), then it is highly unlikely that any packages that come with it are suspicious/unsafe to use. But I would call it a good intuition to double check.

Use Miniconda if you only want a minimal install including Conda and Python.